# Get Specific AD Users from AD Group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to get specific users from specific Groups in Active Directory.

So far I have this:

```
$Groupnames = get-adgroup -Filter "name -like '$Groupfilter'" -Properties * -SearchBase $Grouppath |
    Select-Object Name, @{
        Name='Username';
        Expression={
            Get-ADGroupMember -identity $($_.Name) -Recursive |
            Get-ADUser -Property SamAccountName |
            Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
        }
    }
```

This works to get the Groups with their names. Now I want to get all users from these groups. what works but the formating is completly off. I want this:

```
Name                               Username                                                                                
----                               --------                                                                                
Group1                             user1adm                                                                             
Group2                             {user1adm, user1, user2, user2adm...}                                      
Group3                             {user1adm, user3, user2adm, user6...}
```

But I get this:

```
{user1adm, user1, user2, user2adm...}
```

With that formatting I can't see all users.

My goal at the end is also to exclude users who end with `adm`, but I don't know how to do that.

Can you help me?

Comment: Change `Select Name` to `Select -Expand Name`

Comment: Yeah it helped in a way but it's still like this: `{user1, user1adm, user2, user3...}` Why is there `{}` and `...` at the end. It doesn't show the rest of the users.

Comment: That's just PowerShell way of indicating that there are multiple values in the property. What output _do_ you expect?

Comment: I want to put them into a CSV `{}` are not a huge problem, I can get rid of them. But that it doesn't show all users is the bigger Problem.

Comment: Right, but what would the CSV file look like? One user per line/record?

Comment: No the Group in on the left and the users in one line seperated with the, that are standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember) can return objects of type 'user', 'group' or 'computer', so piping the returned objects straight through to `Get-ADUser` could get you into trouble if one of the objects is not a user.

Having said that, the objects returned from `Get-ADGroupMember` already contain the SamAccountName property you are after, so you can eliminate Get-ADUser from the code.

```
$Groupnames = Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like '$Groupfilter'" -SearchBase $Grouppath | 
                Select-Object Name, 
                @{Name = 'Username'; Expression = { 
                        ($_ | Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive | 
                              Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName | 
                              Where-Object { $_ -notmatch 'adm$' } 
                        ) -join ', '
                    }
                }

# output the result on screen
$Groupnames | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file
$Groupnames | Export-Csv -Path 'Path\To\The\GroupMembers.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, thats exactly what i needed

Comment: Oh no sorry I just found a Problem that I can not solve... When I export all in a CSV and then open that in Excel, the first "" it deletes but the "" in Usernames it doesn't how can I fix this?

Comment: @Forestbird May I ask why you un-accepted the answer?

Comment: @Forestbird Try adding `-UseCulture` to the Export-Csv command

Comment: And the even bigger Problem, at the end of the Usernames it just writes ... when there are to many Usernames!

Comment: sorry I didn't see that problem at first glance